# AlertDialog,savedInstance state and buttons

Tags: android

I was doing some android coding, total newbie at it and i wanted to know if i was doing it right. 
Basically my mainactivity has two edittext where you can type in a username and password. (im storing usernames and passwords in a textfile, this is for school/learning i know its not the way to store them)

In my jave code, i check if the password and username is in the text file with onClick(). if it is not i want to show an alert dialog that says username/password is incorrect try again. 
Im just alittle confused about how i should be using bundle savedInstanceState for this.Let me show you the jave code first.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Triage triage = new Triage();
File passwdFile = new File (this.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "passwords.txt");
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
}
public void onClick(View view){
    if (checkUsername(this.triage, view)){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class));
    }
    else{
        onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState).show();
       }
}

public boolean checkUsername(Triage t, View v){
    EditText username = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.usernameText);
    EditText passwordEntered = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    HashMap<String, Nurse> nurseMap = (HashMap<String, Nurse>)triage.getNurseMap();
    if ((nurseMap.containsKey(username)) && nurseMap.get(username).getPassword().equals(passwordEntered)){
            return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
            dialog.dismiss();}
            });
    builder.setMessage("Try Again")
    .setTitle("Wrong username/password");
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    return dialog;
    }
}
```

Im thinking im calling the onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState).show() wrong, so im asking how do i pass  a savedInstanceState as a parameter? is this correct? I know savedInstanceState is used so you can recreate your activity when the screen changes and i assume an alert dialog is an extension of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very basic use of dialog builder is as

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Hello...")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", dialogClickListener)
        .setNegativeButton("Cancle", dialogClickListener).show();

DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            switch (which)
            {
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    // Yes button clicked
                    break;
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    // No button clicked
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

You should read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html)

Answer (score 1):

The activity's `onCreateDialog` was deprecated with the introduction of fragments. If I were you, I would just use the `AlertDialog.Builder` inline, since this is just for class.

If you are serious about using `onCreateDialog` though, you shouldn't be calling it directly. You should be calling the activity's `showDialog(id)` method and passing an id. The system will call `onCreateDialog(long id)` and pass along the id. The system will show the Dialog you return for you. Make sure you match up showDialog and onCreateDialog so that they either both just have id or both have id & bundle.

If you want to use fragments. You'll need to subclass `DialogFragment` and override the `onCreateDialog` method and do the same thing as the activity's `onCreateDialog` (create and return a Dialog). In you activiy, you create a new instance of your fragment and call `show(getFragmentManager(), "my-tag")` from the instance.

Comment: im interested in the Alert.Dialog.Builder can you tell me more about it or some links for reading?